# NavigationController not dismissing

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller

I have a ViewController(A) which after 3 seconds presents a navigation controller with a relationship to another View Controller(B). Like so:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {            
    let dispatchTime = DispatchTime.now() + .seconds(3)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: dispatchTime) {
        let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Navigation")
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

In ViewController(B) code happens and at some point a function gets triggered:

```
func start(){
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
          self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true)    
    }
}
```

This works the first time and it will reach ViewController(b) again after 3 seconds pass, but nothing happens if start() gets called a second time. Similar thing happens if I try to do self.dismiss() or  `self.navigationController?.popViewController()`.

I have tried a lot of things and have looked through other posts, but I cant find anything helpful for my situation.

Thank you.

Comment: Add the navigation controller programmatically.

Comment: replace this `self.navigationController?` into `self.`

Comment: I tried self.dismiss already, same result.

Comment: Why doesn't this create an infinite loop? Dismissing the nav controller will cause VC A's `viewWillAppear()` to be called again, and *that* instantiates and presents another nav controller, *ad infinitum*.

Comment: the start() function only gets called at certain points and I wanted the VC A to reload. It's more of a fake loading screen that causes VC B to also reload.